# TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

I am using Azure ML with a new compute instance created yesterday.  Kernal is Pandas 3.8
I have these packages: (sorry for the long list, maybe not relevant for the answer)

```
!pip freeze


absl-py==0.15.0
adal==1.2.7
alembic==1.7.6
ansiwrap==0.8.4
antlr4-python3-runtime==4.7.2
applicationinsights==0.11.10
arch==4.14
argcomplete==1.12.3
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
astor==0.8.1
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==21.4.0
autokeras==1.0.16
azure-appconfiguration==1.1.1
azure-batch==11.0.0
azure-cli==2.33.0
azure-cli-core==2.33.0
azure-cli-telemetry==1.0.6
azure-common==1.1.27
azure-core==1.21.1
azure-cosmos==3.2.0
azure-datalake-store==0.0.52
azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
azure-identity==1.7.0
azure-keyvault==1.1.0
azure-keyvault-administration==4.0.0b3
azure-keyvault-keys==4.5.0b4
azure-loganalytics==0.1.1
azure-mgmt-advisor==9.0.0
azure-mgmt-apimanagement==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-appconfiguration==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-applicationinsights==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.61.0
azure-mgmt-batch==16.0.0
azure-mgmt-batchai==7.0.0b1
azure-mgmt-billing==6.0.0
azure-mgmt-botservice==0.3.0
azure-mgmt-cdn==11.0.0
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices==13.0.0
azure-mgmt-compute==23.1.0
azure-mgmt-consumption==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerinstance==9.1.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==8.2.0
azure-mgmt-containerservice==16.4.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.3.0
azure-mgmt-cosmosdb==7.0.0b2
azure-mgmt-databoxedge==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics==0.2.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-datamigration==10.0.0
azure-mgmt-deploymentmanager==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs==4.0.0
azure-mgmt-dns==8.0.0
azure-mgmt-eventgrid==9.0.0
azure-mgmt-eventhub==9.1.0
azure-mgmt-extendedlocation==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-hdinsight==9.0.0
azure-mgmt-imagebuilder==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-iotcentral==9.0.0
azure-mgmt-iothub==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-iothubprovisioningservices==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault==9.3.0
azure-mgmt-kusto==0.3.0
azure-mgmt-loganalytics==12.0.0
azure-mgmt-managedservices==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-managementgroups==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-maps==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-marketplaceordering==1.1.0
azure-mgmt-media==7.0.0
azure-mgmt-monitor==3.0.0
azure-mgmt-msi==0.2.0
azure-mgmt-netapp==6.0.1
azure-mgmt-network==19.3.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-mgmt-policyinsights==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-privatedns==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms==10.0.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservices==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-recoveryservicesbackup==4.0.0
azure-mgmt-redhatopenshift==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-redis==13.1.0
azure-mgmt-relay==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-reservations==0.6.0
azure-mgmt-resource==20.0.0
azure-mgmt-search==8.0.0
azure-mgmt-security==2.0.0b1
azure-mgmt-servicebus==6.0.0
azure-mgmt-servicefabric==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-servicefabricmanagedclusters==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-servicelinker==1.0.0b1
azure-mgmt-signalr==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-sql==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-sqlvirtualmachine==1.0.0b1
azure-mgmt-storage==19.0.0
azure-mgmt-synapse==2.1.0b4
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-web==4.0.0
azure-multiapi-storage==0.7.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage-blob==12.9.0
azure-storage-common==1.4.2
azure-storage-queue==12.1.6
azure-synapse-accesscontrol==0.5.0
azure-synapse-artifacts==0.10.0
azure-synapse-managedprivateendpoints==0.3.0
azure-synapse-spark==0.2.0
azureml-accel-models==1.38.0
azureml-automl-core==1.38.0
azureml-automl-dnn-nlp==1.38.0
azureml-automl-runtime==1.38.0
azureml-cli-common==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-automl-pipeline-steps==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-dataset==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-fairness==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-notebook==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-pipeline-steps==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-reinforcementlearning==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-server==1.38.0
azureml-contrib-services==1.38.0
azureml-core==1.38.0
azureml-datadrift==1.38.0
azureml-dataprep==2.26.0
azureml-dataprep-native==38.0.0
azureml-dataprep-rslex==2.2.0
azureml-dataset-runtime==1.38.0
azureml-defaults==1.38.0
azureml-explain-model==1.38.0
azureml-inference-server-http==0.4.2
azureml-interpret==1.38.0
azureml-mlflow==1.38.0
azureml-opendatasets==1.38.0
azureml-pipeline==1.38.0
azureml-pipeline-core==1.38.0
azureml-pipeline-steps==1.38.0
azureml-responsibleai==1.38.0
azureml-sdk==1.38.0
azureml-telemetry==1.38.0
azureml-tensorboard==1.38.0
azureml-train==1.38.0
azureml-train-automl==1.38.0
azureml-train-automl-client==1.38.0
azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.38.0
azureml-train-core==1.38.0
azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive==1.38.0
azureml-widgets==1.38.0
backcall==0.2.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
bcrypt==3.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bleach==4.1.0
blis==0.2.4
bokeh==2.3.3
Boruta==0.3
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.20.19
botocore==1.23.19
Bottleneck==1.3.2
cached-property==1.5.2
cachetools==4.2.4
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
click==8.0.3
cloudpickle==2.0.0
colorama==0.4.4
colorlover==0.3.0
configparser==3.7.4
contextlib2==21.6.0
contextvars==2.4
convertdate @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/convertdate_1642883757836/work
coremltools @ git+https://github.com/apple/coremltools@13c064ed99ab1da7abea0196e4ddf663ede48aad
cryptography==36.0.1
cufflinks==0.17.3
cycler==0.11.0
cymem==2.0.6
Cython==0.29.26
dask==2.30.0
databricks-cli==0.16.2
dataclasses==0.6
datasets==1.8.0
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
dice-ml==0.7.2
dill==0.3.4
distributed==2.30.1
distro==1.6.0
docker==5.0.3
dotnetcore2==2.1.22
dowhy==0.7
econml==0.12.0
en-core-web-sm @ https://aka.ms/automl-resources/packages/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
encrypted-inference==0.9
entrypoints==0.3
erroranalysis==0.1.29
fabric==2.6.0
fairlearn==0.7.0
fastai==1.0.61
fastprogress==1.0.0
fbprophet==0.5
filelock==3.4.1
fire==0.4.0
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
flatbuffers==2.0
fsspec==2022.1.0
funcy==1.17
fusepy==3.0.1
future==0.18.2
gast==0.2.2
gensim==3.8.3
gevent==1.3.6
gitdb==4.0.9
GitPython==3.1.18
google-auth==1.35.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
graphviz @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-graphviz_1602262908037/work
greenlet==1.1.2
grpcio==1.43.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
h5py==3.1.0
HeapDict==1.0.1
holidays==0.9.11
horovod==0.19.1
htmlmin==0.1.12
huggingface-hub==0.0.19
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.3
ImageHash==4.2.1
imageio==2.15.0
imbalanced-learn==0.7.0
immutables==0.16
importlib-metadata==4.8.3
importlib-resources==5.4.0
inference-schema==1.3.0
interpret-community==0.24.1
interpret-core==0.2.7
invoke==1.6.0
ipykernel==5.5.6
ipython==7.16.3
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.6.5
isodate==0.6.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
javaproperties==0.5.2
jedi==0.18.0
jeepney==0.7.1
Jinja2==2.11.2
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==0.14.1
json-logging-py==0.2
jsondiff==1.3.1
jsonpickle==2.1.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-console==6.4.0
jupyter-core==4.9.1
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.2
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
keras-nightly==2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keras-tuner==1.1.0
keras2onnx==1.6.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
kmodes==0.11.1
knack==0.8.2
kt-legacy==1.0.4
liac-arff==2.5.0
lightgbm==2.3.0
llvmlite==0.36.0
locket==0.2.1
lunardate==0.2.0
Mako==1.1.6
Markdown==3.3.6
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
missingno==0.5.0
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.2.0
mkl-random==1.1.0
mkl-service==2.3.0
ml-wrappers==0.0.6
mlflow==1.23.1
mlflow-skinny==1.23.0
mlxtend==0.19.0
mpmath==1.2.1
msal==1.16.0
msal-extensions==0.3.1
msgpack==1.0.3
msrest==0.6.21
msrestazure==0.6.4
multimethod==1.5
multiprocess==0.70.12.2
murmurhash==1.0.6
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.1.3
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
nest-asyncio==1.5.4
networkx==2.5
nimbusml==1.8.0
nltk==3.6.7
notebook==6.4.7
numba==0.53.1
numexpr==2.8.1
numpy==1.18.5
nvidia-ml-py3==7.352.0
oauthlib==3.1.1
olefile==0.46
onnx==1.7.0
onnxconverter-common==1.6.0
onnxmltools==1.4.1
onnxruntime==1.8.0
opencv-python-headless==4.5.5.62
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.1.5
pandas-ml==0.6.1
pandas-profiling==3.1.0
pandocfilters==1.5.0
papermill==1.2.1
paramiko==2.9.2
parso==0.7.1
partd==1.2.0
pathlib2==2.3.6
pathspec==0.9.0
patsy==0.5.2
pexpect==4.8.0
phik==0.12.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pillow_1602788709045/work
pkginfo==1.8.2
plac==0.9.6
plotly==5.5.0
pmdarima==1.1.1
portalocker==2.3.2
preshed==2.0.1
prometheus-client==0.12.0
prometheus-flask-exporter==0.18.7
prompt-toolkit==3.0.24
property-cached==1.6.4
protobuf==3.19.3
psutil==5.9.0
psycopg2 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/psycopg2_1612298609104/work
ptyprocess==0.7.0
py4j==0.10.9.2
pyarrow==3.0.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycaret==2.3.6
pycocotools==2.0.0
pycparser==2.21
pydantic==1.9.0
pydot==1.4.2
PyGithub==1.55
Pygments==2.11.2
PyJWT==2.3.0
pyLDAvis==3.3.1
PyMeeus @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pymeeus_1615809745702/work
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pynndescent==0.5.6
pyod==0.9.7
pyodbc===4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL==21.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.6
pyreadline==2.1
pyrsistent==0.18.0
PySocks==1.7.1
pyspark==3.2.0
pystan==2.19.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytorch-transformers==1.0.0
pytz==2021.3
PyWavelets==1.1.1
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq==22.3.0
qtconsole==5.2.2
QtPy==2.0.1
querystring-parser==1.2.4
rai-core-flask==0.2.4
raiwidgets==0.16.0
regex==2022.1.18
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
responsibleai==0.16.0
rsa==4.8
s3transfer==0.5.0
sacremoses==0.0.47
scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scikit-plot==0.3.7
scipy==1.5.2
scp==0.13.6
scrapbook==0.5.0
seaborn==0.11.2
SecretStorage==3.3.1
semver==2.13.0
Send2Trash==1.8.0
sentencepiece==0.1.96
seqeval==1.2.2
setuptools-git==1.2
shap==0.39.0
sip==4.19.24
six==1.16.0
skl2onnx==1.4.9
sklearn-pandas==1.7.0
slicer==0.0.7
smart-open==1.9.0
smmap==5.0.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
spacy==2.1.8
sparse==0.13.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.31
sqlparse==0.4.2
srsly==1.0.5
sshtunnel==0.1.5
statsmodels==0.10.2
sympy==1.9
tabulate==0.8.9
tangled-up-in-unicode==0.1.0
tblib==1.7.0
tenacity==8.0.1
tensorboard==2.1.1
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.12.1
testpath==0.5.0
textblob==0.17.1
textwrap3==0.9.2
thinc==7.0.8
threadpoolctl @ file:///tmp/tmp9twdgx9k/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
tifffile==2020.9.3
tokenizers==0.10.3
toolz==0.11.2
torch==1.10.1
torch-tb-profiler==0.3.1
torchvision==0.9.1
tornado==6.1
tqdm==4.62.3
traitlets==4.3.3
transformers==4.5.1
typing-extensions==4.0.1
umap-learn==0.5.2
urllib3==1.26.7
uuid==1.30
visions==0.7.4
waitress==2.0.0
wasabi==0.9.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.2.3
websockets==9.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
widgetsnbextension==3.5.2
wordcloud==1.8.1
wrapt==1.12.1
xgboost==0.90
xmltodict==0.12.0
xxhash==2.0.2
yellowbrick==1.3.post1
zict==2.0.0
zipp==3.6.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

I am using scikit learn and numpy, and whenever I run methods like
.describe() I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

the actual code? Last line its the only one with the error above

```
# azureml-core of version 1.0.72 or higher is required
# azureml-dataprep[pandas] of version 1.1.34 or higher is required
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = 'x'
resource_group = 'RG-Architecture-Playground'
workspace_name = 'mlplayground'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='WineDataset')
df = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
df.head(10)

len(df)

df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
df.isnull().sum()


from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
names = df.columns
d = scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=names)
scaled_df.head()

# Basic descriptive and statistics for each column
scaled_df.describe()
```

Comment: Please show the actual code that leads up to that error.

Comment: question updated to add the code which is only the .describe line